# Find all numbers that satisfy the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus

Find all numbers c that satisfy the conclusion of the mean value theorem for the following function and interval:$$f(x)=3x^2+2x+2  \tag{[-1,1]}$$so far I have $$f'(x)=6x+2$$$$6x+2=-1$$$$x=-1/2$$and$$6x+2=1$$$$x=-\frac{1}{6}$$I know both of these are wrong, and the written answer is 0, but I don't see how to get the correct answer.

Comment: what does the mean value theorem say...?

Answer (score 2):

$$
f(1) = 7, f(-1) = 3
$$
Mean value theorem states, for some c in [a, b] with a < b,
$$
f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a},
$$
As, you mentioned,
$$
f'(x) = 6x + 2
$$
Can you solve now?

Comment: I SEE- I plugged the interval values into the derivative of the function instead of the original function!

Comment: This is a great explanation that I was simply missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$f(1) = 3\cdot 1^2 + 2\cdot 1 + 2 = 7$.

$f(-1) = 3\cdot (-1)^2 + 2\cdot (-1) + 2 = 3$.

Thus: $f(1) - f(-1) = (1 - (-1))\cdot f'(c)$ gives:

$7 - 3 = 2\cdot f'(c)$.

So: $f'(c) = 2 \to 6c + 2 = 2 \to c = 0$